Open External ms-outlook protocol in Action.OpenUrl adative card not work in MS Teams
I faced issue when i create a adaptive card using action OpenUrl with ms-outlook protocol in MS teams. When I clicked on button, it not redirect to MS outlook. But when change to mode develop in VSCode it worked
My adaptive card:
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Click the button to open an email template."
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Open Email Template",
      "url": "ms-outlook://events/new?title=New%20Meeting&start=2024-09-19T08:00:00+7&end=2024-09-19T08:30:00+7&attendees=someone@email.com&to=someone@email.com&body=Th%E1%BB%9Di%20gian%20b%E1%BA%AFt%20%C4%91%E1%BA%A7u%202024-09-19T08%3A00%20%0ATh%E1%BB%9Di%20gian%20k%E1%BA%BFt%20th%C3%BAc%202024-09-19T08%3A3019T18:00:00+7"
    }
  ]
}

Can you help me resolve that.
Thank
When I clicked button with action URL i think it will outlook application
There are my test in VSCode:
Adaptive card in VSCode
Redirect to MS outlook
But in teams not work
